# How can I replace 'ß' by 'ss' in an attribute table of a shapefile (arcmap)? ASCII error

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcmap

I'm really new at python coding so please answer in detail and not too harsh..
I'm trying to replace the German umlaut 'ß' in an attribute table of a shapefile by 'ss' and am doing this by using the field calculator where you can add a python code block.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
def ecode(file, name, test):
    test.decode("utf-8")
    test.replace("\xe1", "ss")
    test.encode("utf-8")
    return test
```

Instead of "\xe1" I've also used "U+00DF" and "\xdf".

This error message occurs:

## ERROR: ascii codec can't encode character u'\xdf' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)

The streetname in this field of the attribute table is 'Zuccalistraße 21a', so obviously ß is the problem which is out of the ASCII range (there it >number 200).
What can I do to replace it?
I've searched the internet for 5 hours now....

Would love to get some answers!
Kind regards,
Ayla

Comment: Hi @AylaLyra, you need to assign the values of the function to a variable in order for the functions to work, since they are not in-place! Check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So obviously, it's a problem with the decoding. 
When I try

```
def ecode(file, name, test):
    test=test.decode("utf-8")
    test=test.replace(u"\xdf", "ss")
    test=test.encode("utf-8")
    return test
```

I get the Error message:

File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xdf' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)

Now I got an answer to the problem: 
I found that when you enter

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")
```

to the function, it works fine!!
So thanks for trying to help me, have a nice day :)

Cheers, 
Ayla

Comment: You didn't paste my code entirely, because I have done the same thing you did in a simpler way @AylaLyra :) , as I have a line in my code # coding=utf-8 , which when you paste on top and run the code, will perform the same thing. I would suggest to try my code again with this information, when you run it python script.py, you get the output Zuccalistrasse 21a –

Answer (score 2):

`decode`, and `encode` and `replace` do not work in-place. Try `test = test.decode('utf-8')`, `test = test.encode('utf-8')` and `test = test.replace("\xe1", "ss")`.

**It means that the `decode` and `replace` lines have no effect on `test`.** Then the third line tries to `encode` the object, **but it has not been decoded**, so it doesn't work.

That said, you are still going to have a problem after that. Here is what I would do :

```
test = test.decode("utf-8")
test = test.replace(u"\xdf", "ss")
test = test.encode("utf-8")
```

or

```
test = test.decode("utf-8")
test = test.replace(u"ß", "ss")
test = test.encode("utf-8")
```

whichever looks the most readable to you.

You could also not decode/encode it and just do `test = test.replace(u"\xdf".encode("utf-8"), "ss")` or `test = test.replace("ß", "ss")` but generally it's better to handle `unicode` objects so I would say decoding and encoding is a good practice.

Comment: Hey Ashargin, thanks for your help! I'll write the comment in an answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `casefold` and `capitalize` for `python3`

```
In [6]: s = 'Zuccalistraße 21a'                                                                                                               

In [7]: s.casefold()                                                                                                                          
Out[7]: 'zuccalistrasse 21a'

In [8]: s.casefold().capitalize()                                                                                                             
Out[8]: 'Zuccalistrasse 21a'
```

For `python2`, the functions `decode`, `replace` and `encode` are not `in-place` function, but they return a value, so you need to assign the return value of the function to a variable to make your code.

Also note the `# coding=utf-8` declared above. This is in accordance of [PEP-263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/#defining-the-encoding)

```
# coding=utf-8

s = 'Zuccalistraße 21a'
s = s.decode("utf-8").replace(u"\xdf", "ss").encode("utf-8")
print(s)
```

The output will be

```
Zuccalistrasse 21a
```

Comment: Hi Devesh! Thanks for your help. I'll write my comment in an answer below :)

Comment: If you check the answer again, I have mentioned that the first solution is `python3`, and the second solution is `python2` @AylaLyra

Comment: Ahh I see that's why it is not working with casefold.

Comment: Great glad to help :) If the answer helped you, please consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the tick next to the answer. Also please consider reading  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: It helps, really, but still I'm with the same problem :( sorry for that. The decoding is not working..

Comment: Please paste the last code as it is, it worked for me in python2.7 @AylaLyra

Comment: you can see it in my answer below :)

Comment: You didn't paste my code entirely, because I have done the same thing you did in a simpler way @AylaLyra :) , as I have a line in my code  `# coding=utf-8` , which when you paste on top and run the code, will perform the same thing. I would suggest to try my code again with this information, when you run it `python script.py`, you get the output `Zuccalistrasse 21a`